# Neural Network predicting Plain text for respective Encrypted text

Tags: encryption, neural-network, cryptography

Suppose I have a function called `encrypt(string)`. which takes some string divides it into `k` blocks. and encrypt it in some fashion. I used this function to encrypt some 1000-2000 sample text and gathered there respective encrypted text.

Then I trained a Neural Network on that data i.e encrypted text and respective plain text. So my question is it possible that suppose I feed thousands of examples to the `neural network` then It'll someday reverse engineer the entire encryption logic and for any encrypted text it will return corresponding plain text with higher accuracy ?

Thanks ✌️

Comment: Can you edit your questions title to be about the content of your questions, instead of the area/field of your question?

Comment: Replace "neural network" with "magic black box" and what you're basically asking is whether a cryptosystem be broken by means of a [chosen-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack). For classical ciphers like Vigenère and Playfair, the answer is yes. But in modern cryptosystems, this type of attack is to all attempts and purposes impossible, except perhaps in a few cases where your black box contains a quantum computer.